# Why JVM doesn't throw out of memory error even if the memory reached the maximum heap size?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, heap-memory, heap-profiling

I am running a Java programming which creates more objects in memory inside a while loop.
I set the maximum heap size as 10MB. I am watching task manager, the JVM runs even after 10 MB.
I am expecting out of memory. But it is not throwing , it is keep printing a statement in while loop.

**`java -Xmx10m Main`**

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        String s1 = "01011001100100";
        char[] charArray = s1.toCharArray();
        int index = 0;
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer temp = new StringBuffer();
        
        while(index < charArray.length){
            System.out.println(index+" : "+charArray[index]);
            if(charArray[index] == '1' && charArray[index--] == '0'){ ***--- This is buggy code***
                result.append(1);
            } else {
                temp.append(charArray[index]);
            }
            index++;
        }
        System.out.println("Result >"+result);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Why JVM doesn't throw out of memory error even if the memory reached the maximum heap size?

Why?

Because the `-xmx` parameter sets the maximum Java heap size, NOT the total memory size for the Java process.  A lot of a JVM's memory utilization is not in the heap.  This includes:

- memory used to hold the code for the `java` executable and shared native libraries
- memory used for the native heap; e.g. `malloc` calls in native code
- memory used for metaspace
- memory used for thread stacks
- memory used when a file is mapped into memory
- and so on.

Some of the above can lead to an OOME (for example, failure to allocate a new thread stack), but the heap size that you set with `-xmx` does not limit them in any way.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. How can see the Heap through any GUI , also the Stack. I want to see visually.

Comment: What do you mean "see"?  Do you mean track how much memory is used?  (Generally this is not a useful thing to do ...)

Comment: Yes. I want to just monitor , how memory is utilized and want to understand garbage collection.